# Call objective C macro from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have created a CLogger objective C class and defined below macro

```
#define CLogError(fmt, ...) //remaining code
```

I am able to access CLogError in objective C files and call it. But above macro is not accessible in swift file. How can I call this from swift?

Comment: not possible. you need to reimplement it in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at the moment. You can always define it in Swift as a global function:

```
func CLogError(fmt : String, strings : String...) { ... }
```